# The "big bracket" in Lie bialgebras

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, bialgebras

I am looking for a well-written document such as a survey article or textbook that explores the subject of the "big bracket". This concept is briefly introduced in the appendix of Yvette Kosmann-Schwarzbach's article, on page 61.

[Lie bialgebras, Poisson Lie groups and dressing transformations](http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/cmat/kosmann/lnp2.pdf)

> I am particularly interested in a text that provides in-depth information about the computational aspects within the realm of Lie bialgebras. More precisely, I'm interested in studying Jacobi identities that describe the coproduct by means of the big bracket.

Comment: There are much more details (and references) in the survey by the same author "Jacobian quasi bialgebras and quasi-Poisson Lie groups" in "Mathematical aspects of classical field theory (Seattle, WA, 1991). Vol. 132. Contemp. Math. Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1992".

Comment: @Adrien Many thanks for the nice reference. Another useful article that I just found, by the same author: crochets de Schouten et cohomologies d'algèbres de Lie, Comptes rendus Acad. Sci., Paris, 312, Série I (1991), 123-126.